# Override host page CSS rules with ones from the extension without tons of !important

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension which adds some elements to pages. I'd like those elements to look exactly the same on every site. Considering the fact that there are some, ugh, developers, who write their CSS rules with "!important", is there a way to override such rules without adding "!important" to every rule in extension's CSS? Maybe there are some CSS3 or Chrome/Webkit's proprietary methods to do so?

Comment: Nothing can override `!important` except an `!important` later in the cascade

Answer (score 0):

No, actually if someone use !important in the css rules there is no other way to overwrite without putting !important.  For example,

`body{background:transparent !important}`

can be overwritten by using

`html body{background:blue !importamt}`

Answer (score 0):

Define your class with parent element class. You could also use !important keyword.

i.e.

```
<div class='my_parent'>
  <div class='class-1'>...</div>
  <div class='class-2'>...</div>
</div>
```

in your .css file

```
div.my_parent class-1{..}
div.my_parent class-2{..}
```

Comment: -1 How does this help? Can you provide a concrete example (http://jsfiddle.net) of this overriding rules with `!important`?